# Passing bytearray from C# client header

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpclient

I need to pass a byte array from C# client to Java server. The java server is not under my control and it expects byte array from the request header of C# client. So I need to pass a byte array from the request header of the C# client. My code is as below.

C# client code

```
 byte[] outToken =getOutToken();
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.101:8285/HealthCheck");
     request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Negotiate " + outToken  );
```

Java server code

```
Map headersMap = (Map) headers;
String authHeader = (String) headersMap.get("Authorization");
String authToken = authHeader.substring(10).trim();
```

In java code from authToken variable it is suppose to get the outToken which I passed from the C# client. But when evaluating I'm getting 'System.Byte[]' as the value for the authToken.

What is the best way to pass a byte array from the C# client request header. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't seem to expect a byte array at all - you need to encode it the way the server side expects it. That might be a Base-64 encoding or something entirely different. However, by the look of it, you really simply need to use HTTP Negotiate authorization.

Comment: yes, the server expects a String. But I need the same byte array which is passing from the client to regenerate from server side. It is ok if I have to some changes in serve side as well.

Comment: In that case, just use Base-64, that's the typical way of converting byte array to a string (web-)safely. In C#, it's as simple as `Convert.ToBase64String`.